# Is it possible to draw a graph CIE standard chromaticity diagram in plotly?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to display such a graph in the plotly, but I did not find anything like this in the documentation.
[graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXytw.png)

I found only `color.plotting.plot_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931` in color library which does what i need but with `matplotlib`. My app is using dash + plotly so can't use matplotlib.

Comment: plotly doesn't have chromaticity diagrams built in, so you would probably have to construct it from scratch. maybe you could somehow look at the underlying data in matplotlib's chromaticity diagram and recreate it in plotly

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not the most elegant but you could use [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour) to draw the image via Matplotlib to a png byte stream and then use it as a layout background image in Plotly, then you could cherry-pick the bits you need from the [`colour.plotting.diagrams.plot_spectral_locus`](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/develop/colour/plotting/diagrams.py#L98) definition to plot the spectral locus and the wavelengths.

```py
import base64
import colour
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go

colour.plotting.colour_style()
# Resolution of the background image divided by 10, i.e. 1000px here.
plt.rcParams.update({"figure.figsize": (10.00, 10.00)})

# Drawing the background image with Matplotlib.
figure, axes = colour.plotting.diagrams.plot_chromaticity_diagram_colours(
    diagram_colours="RGB", axes_visible=False, standalone=False)
figure.subplots_adjust(top=1, bottom=0, right=1, left=0, hspace=0, wspace=0) 

buffer = io.BytesIO()
plt.savefig(buffer, format="png")
data_png = "data:image/png;base64," + base64.b64encode(buffer.getbuffer()).decode("utf8")
plt.close()

# Displaying it with Plotly.
figure = go.Figure()
figure.update_layout(
    width=1000,
    height=1000,
    xaxis=dict(
        range=[0, 1]
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        range=[0, 1]
    ),
)
figure.update_yaxes(
    scaleanchor="x",
    scaleratio=1,
  )
figure.add_layout_image(
    dict(
        source=data_png,
        xref="x",
        yref="y",
        x=0,
        y=1,
        sizex=1,
        sizey=1,
        sizing="stretch",
        layer="below"
    )
)
figure.show()
```

[image]