# How to draw chromaticity diagram (CIE) in Flutter?

Tags: python, flutter, dart, matplotlib, color-space

I am trying to draw this kind of chromaticity diagram in Flutter:

[image: Example chromaticity diagram]

[Image source](https://www.originlab.com/fileexchange/details.aspx?fid=168)

Here is what I have discovered:

- I've figured out a formula from [this resource](https://peteroupc.github.io/colorgen.html#CIE_XYZ), but don't know how to draw it up.
- I also found a library in Python which can draw it: https://github.com/colour-science/colour. But the way pyplot shows images seems to be different from custom paint in Flutter.

What should I do?

Comment: I suggested using Matplotlib to draw the image and load it in Plotly in another thread, this might be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76024306/is-it-possible-to-draw-a-graph-cie-standard-chromaticity-diagram-in-plotly/76033328#76033328

Comment: @KelSolaar I know it can be drawn in Python but is there any way to draw chromaticity diagram in mobile platform ?

Comment: I’m not aware of anything readily made. One approach like we do in Colour is to render on a raster and clip with a vector path, another one is to generate a Delaunay triangulation of the horseshoe shape by taking samples on and within the spectral locus and have vertex colours interpolation.

Comment: A pedantic note: chromacity diagrams should be drawn in B&W. The colours will add confusion (you need to be in deep in colour theory to not misunderstand the colours). In fact: all colours on the diagrams in the questions have different chromacity compared the expected value reading x and y axis. And your diagrams have little yellow AND little blue (not cyan): a very odd choice of projection. Often you have no yellow and dark colour (subtractive mixing) or yellow and good blues (additive and balanced). To me your figures seems using clipping badly.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi the figures are copied from the Internet, sorry if it annoys you. This is the original figure: https://www.originlab.com/fileexchange/details.aspx?fid=168

Comment: If you want to copy, copy them from Wikipedia: they are not randomly generated, but with much more quality control. But if you want to include similar figures, what should that figure tell the readers? The figure you linked is very misleading. It can only create further confusion on a complex field. (some uses cases: colour mixing or to show gamut extension, white point lines, but the above figure fails on both, and very badly).

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to use representational colors inside a chromaticity diagram. Quite literally, that is the *standard* presentation. The suggestion that they should use only B&W is weird... To make the real/not real colors obvious, one way is fill the sRGB bounding triangle with a gradient, using sRGB primaries in each corner, but then a dimmed grad under the chromaticity diagram overall, as here in the first figure in the article: [*Realities and Myths of Color*](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2022/09/realities-myths-contrast-color/#in-the-eye-of-the-beholder-or-the-mind).